# PHP7 Bitwise shifts by negative number will throw an ArithmeticError in PHP

Tags: php, bitwise-operators, php-7

We're looking to switch to a PHP7 server and are running some compatibility checks on existing code of a website. One of the problems found is with the following function and the Bitwise shifts by a negative number.

Apparently this will throw errors in PHP7. I'll admit I don't fully understand how this arithmetic works, but I was wondering if anyone had a suggesting on how to modify the function to #1 maintain the functionality and #2 become PHP7 compliant.

```
/**
 * Right shift with zero fill.
 *
 * @param integer $a number to shift
 * @param integer $b number of bits to shift
 * @return integer
 */
public function zeroFill($a, $b){
    return ($a >= 0) ? ($a >> $b) : ($a >> $b) & (PHP_INT_MAX >> ($b - 1));
}
```

Comment: look up the function str_pad, maybe you can use it to work around the problem

Answer (score 0):

The ArithmeticError is thrown when an mathematical calculation doesn't happen as normally expected, which in this case could lead to values outside of the possible bounds of an integer. ([See documentation here](http://docs.php.net/manual/uk/class.arithmeticerror.php))

Your function is already validating this and limiting the operation for a PHP_INT_MAX, so there is no problem there.

As to remove the alert message thrown by your verification plugin, you need to cover the function with a try/catch block in order to capture a possible ArithmeticError. This way the function would be like:

```
public function zeroFill($a, $b){
    try {
        return ($a >= 0) ? ($a >> $b) : ($a >> $b) & (PHP_INT_MAX >> ($b - 1));
    } catch(ArithmeticError $error) {
        // Do your logic to treat this kind of error
    }
    return $a; // Or return something you would want
}
```

Also, using the str_pad is always a good alternative.